# Tracking status of sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a sidekiq worker that launches another sidekiq worker; however, I don't have a way to know when that worker is finished. I ran across this: [Rails how to tell if a sidekiq worker is done with perform_async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940007/rails-how-to-tell-if-a-sidekiq-worker-is-done-with-perform-async?rq=1) but this is apparently old and I get this error when trying to call `Sidekiq::Status`

```
[12] pry(#<ScanWorker>)> Sidekiq::Status::get_all
NameError: uninitialized constant Sidekiq::Status
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `block in load_missing_constant'
Caused by NameError: uninitialized constant Sidekiq::Status
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:60:in `block in load_missing_constant'
```

Comment: [sidekiq-status](https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status) is a gem